# Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Future<String>' in type cast

Tags: oop, flutter, dart

I am gettting this error ,can anyone help me to sort out this error

```
static Future<String> get_video_lecture_subject(int schoolId,int classroom) async {

  var body;
   body = jsonEncode({
  "school_id": schoolId,
  "classroom": classroom,
  });

  final response = await http.post(
      'https://b5c4tdo0hd.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/testing/get-video-lecture-subjects',
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: body,
  );

   print(response.body.toString());
   return response.body.toString();
 }
```

i have used above function in getpref() function

```
 getpref() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    int classNo = int.parse(prefs.getString("class")[0]);
    int schoolId = prefs.getInt("school_id");

      print("hello");
      response=(await ApiService.get_video_lecture_subject(schoolId, classNo)) as Future<String> ;
      print(response);
  }
```

Comment: does print(response.toString()) cause the same error?

Comment: it prints,that works but

Comment: response=(await ApiService.get_video_lecture_subject(schoolId, classNo)) as Future<String> ;  ,

Comment: this line is causing error

Comment: String response=await ApiService.get_video_lecture_subject(schoolId, classNo);

Answer (score 0):

The expression:

```
(await ApiService.get_video_lecture_subject(schoolId, classNo)) as Future<String>
```

calls your method `get_video_lecture_subject`. That returns a `Future<String>`.
You then await that future, which results in a `String`.

Then you try to cast that `String` to `Future<String>`. That fails because a string is not a future.

Try removing the `as Future<String>`.

Comment: A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Future<String>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Future<String>'

Comment: i have used the response of

Comment: Future<String> response;

Comment: If the type of `response` is `Futue<String>`, then you can't assign a string to it. So, what do you *want* to do instead?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line with this

```dart
      final res = await ApiService.get_video_lecture_subject(schoolId, classNo);
```

Update: Change the variable name (maybe it's type was initialized as Future)

Comment: A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Future<String>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Future<String>'

Answer (score 0):

Check out this sample example and let me know if it works

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  getPrefs();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

void getPrefs() async {
  String value = await yourfunction();
  print(value);
}

Future<String> yourfunction() {
  final c = new Completer<String>();

  // Below is the sample example you can do your api calling here
  Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
    c.complete("you should see me second");
  });
  // Process your thigs above and send the string via the complete method.
  // in you case it will be c.complete(response.body);

  return c.future;
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child:
              /* FutureBuilder<String>(
            future: yourfunction(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data);
              }

              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }), */
              Text('')),
    ));
  }
}
```